# How can I use Flex Viewer 2.2 with ArcIMS 9.3 or 10?

Tags: flex, arcims

I am one of the users that is currently using ArcIMS to build a web GIS,so I have not had migrated to ArcGIS Server yet, therefore can I use Flex viewer 2.2 in ArcIMS 9.3 or 10? Will it cause any problem with it ? If so, can any one help me  how to start learning with flex viewer for (API)?

Comment: yes, ArcIMS10, or 9.3, the second part from the Q, is it, any advice for learning Flex API .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use it. Here is ESRI's example:
http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/flex/samples/index.html?sample=ArcIMS

You should look into the ArcIMSMapServiceLayer class:
http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/flex/apiref/com/esri/ags/layers/ArcIMSMapServiceLayer.html

Comment: Thank you very much Anthony -GISCOE- , but is there any video tutorial about learning Api for Flex.

Answer (score 1):

> is there any video tutorial about
>   learning Api for Flex

Start off here: [Adobe Flex in a week](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/videotraining.html)

Then check out the latest vids from Esri on Flex.

- [Go here](http://proceedings.esri.com/library/userconf/devsummit10/tech.html) and type Flex in search box = plenty of videos to get u started

Comment: Thank you very much Simon for helping me ............thank you again

Comment: Thank you is all and well, but an up vote means more :)